# How to set axis for multiple subplots of pictures in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

```
clear all; close all; clc;
A = im2double(imread('cameraman.jpg'));
figure(1)
imshow(A)

C = chunking(A,400,400) % separates picture;
[m n] = size(C);
k = 1;
figure(1)
for i = 1:m
    for j = 1:n
        subplot(m,n,k)
        imshow(C{i,j})
        axis off;
        k = k + 1;

    end
end
```

So In the above code, I am trying to separate a picture into 400x400 pixel chunks. Since the image is not a multiple of 400x400, it will have unequal sections on the border and bottom right corner (still a square image). However, when I use subplot, it resizes the last chunk to be the same size. I tried playing around with get and set position but it gives that the width and height for each subplot is the same?![enter image description here][1]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1D1r.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You want to resize the axes if you have less than 400 pixels to display.  You should store the handle to each subplot and then resize it if it needs to be smaller.

Your call to subplot should look like this:

```
h = subplot(m,n,k);
num_rows = size(C{i,j}, 1);
num_cols = size(C{i,j}, 2);
set(h, 'units', 'pixels')
old_axes_pos = get(h, 'position');
new_axes_pos = old_axes_pos;
if num_cols < 400
   new_axes_pos(3) = num_cols; % Make this axes narrower
end
% If the figure cannot be full height
if num_rows < 400
   new_axes_pos(4) = num_rows;  % Make this axes shorter
   new_axes_pos(2) = old_axes_pos(2) + (400 - num_rows); % Move the bottom up
end
set(h, 'position', new_axes_pos) % Change the size of the figure
```